# Распространяются данные на конкретную директорию права и на поддиректории в UNIX-подобных OS?

Tags: unix, права-доступа

Недавно я задавал узкоспециализированный вопрос [Ошибка "Permission denied (13) " при попытке отправить данные через rsync в директорию с правами доступа 777 при использовании не-root аккаунта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1396194/193415), но ответ на него вызывал лишь новые вопросы. Похоже, я ввобще не понимаю эту концепцию, а потому задал этот, более общий вопрос.

Итак, правильно ли я понял, что когда мы вызываем `chmod` (скажем, чтобы дать право на чтение и запись), то по умолчанию разрешение распространяется только на файлы, содержащиеся непосредственно в данной директории, но не в поддиректориях? (Я ещё слышал что-то про то, то можно дать разрешение рекурсивно).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Для рекурсивного применения команд `chgrp` или `chown` достаточно использовать ключ `-R`
2. Ну наверное самое для Вас интересное. Даже рекурсивное изменение группы, владельца или прав на файлы и директории применит  изменения только для существующих, на данный момент, объектов. Тоесть если у Вас к следующей синхронизации добавятся новые файлы или папки Вы получите аналогичную проблему с ошибкой доступа
3. (по порядку но не по значению) покурите утилиту `acl` она позволяет более гибко управлять правами доступа

```bsh
apt install acl

# так можно установить права для всех 
# создаваемых внутри папки `/var/www` 
# файлов и директорий для пользователя `non_root_admin`. 
# Причем обратите внимание на то, что используется `X` а не `x` 
# поскольку этот флаг нужен только для папок

setfacl -dm u:non_root_admin:rwX /var/www

# Так Вы примениете права rw для уже существующих 
# в директории файлов для пользователя `non_root_admin`
find /var/www -type f -exec setfacl -m u:non_root_admin:rw {}\;

# Так Вы примениете права rwx для уже существующих 
# в директории папок для пользователя `non_root_admin`
find /var/www -type d -exec setfacl -m u:non_root_admin:rwX {}\;


# Так Вы установите права rwX по умолчанию для уже существующих 
# в директории папок и создаваемых в них объектов для пользователя `non_root_admin`
find /var/www -type d -exec setfacl -dm u:non_root_admin:rwX {}\;
...
```

> Надеюсь дальше сами разберетесь

##### P.S.

> Не знаю зачем Вам в данном случае нужен `rsync` но если я правильно понимаю, то Вам больше, для Ваших целей, подойдет любая `VCS` ну к примеру `Git`

##### P.P.S

> У `acl` тоже есть возможность рекурсивного применения, но мне оно как-то не зашло, поскольку при применениии к уже существующим объектам флагов `rwX` у файлов тоже появляется флаг на запуск. Поэтому я делаю через `find`

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! "Не знаю зачем Вам в данном случае нужен rsync" - потому что я деплою только собранное приложение, но не исходный код, а Git предназначен в основном для управления исходным кодом.

Comment: @БоковГлеб, немного дополнил ответ.